# How do I pass a variable into a jquery load selector?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, selector

I am loading a page inside of a div using ajax.  It's all working fine when I have a fixed selector div such as -

```
$('.ajaxurl').click(function(){
    $('.selected-blog').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Here '.selected-blog' is a fixed entry.

However I have multiple .ajaxurl links on the page, each with it's own respective '.selected-blog' div and so I want to be able to load the source into a different div depending on which .ajaxurl link was clicked.  In other words, each .ajaxurl link will need to have a corresponding unique .selected-blog-[id] class and clicking the link will need to pass the [id] variable into the function so that it can be appended to the selector.

I have tried giving the .ajaxurl link an id to pass to the jquery as a variable, so that the body code is -

```
<div class="teaser-id<?php print $id; ?>">
  <a class="ajaxurl" id ="id<?php print $id; ?>" href="[pagelink]">Click me</a>  
  stuff here
</div> 
<div class="selected-blog-id<?php print $id; ?>"></div>     

[this above code repeats for each teaser in the list]
```

And the jquery code is -

```
$('.ajaxurl').click(function(){
     var x = this.id;
     $('.selected-blog-,'+x).load($(this).attr('href'));
     return false;
});
```

But I can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong?

(Finally - and this is an additional point for if it has an impact on the solution - I'd want to hide the teaser-[id] div, so if the variable passed can also be used for this  .hide() function that would be great!)

How do I do this?!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to make your html so complex. You can keep it simple and use jquery [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next div with the class `selected-blog-id` to load the content into.
Something along these lines should work for you:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="teaser-id">
    <a class="ajaxurl" href="[pagelink]">Click me</a>  
    stuff here
</div> 
<div class="selected-blog-id"></div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('.ajaxurl').click(function(e) {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    // hide the teaser
    $parent.hide();

    // load content into the next div with selected-blog-id
    $parent.next('.selected-blog-id').load(this.href);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out your `ajaxurl` element as `id ="id<?php print $id; ?>"`, did you intent to do `id ="<?php print $id; ?>"` instead?

Comment: I had added the text 'id' to those sections as $id is a number and from my understanding you can't start an id with a number.  So the final result would be id="id3" for example.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things seem to have been mistyped or else you might want to double check the below:

```
<div class="teaser-id-<?php print $id; ?>">
 <a class="ajaxurl" id ="blog-<?php print $id; ?>" href="[pagelink]">Click me</a>  
 <!-- <a class="ajaxurl" id ="id<?php print $id; ?>" href="[pagelink]">Click me</a> -->  
 stuff here
</div> 
<div class="selected-blog-<?php print $id; ?>"></div> 
<!-- <div class="selected-blog-id<?php print $id; ?>"></div> -->   

[this above code repeats for each teaser in the list]
```

jQuery

```
$('.ajaxurl').click(function(){
    var x = this.id.replace("blog-", '');
    //$('.selected-blog-,'+x).load($(this).attr('href'));
    $('.selected-blog-' + x).load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
        $(".teaser-id-" + x).hide();
    });
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE**
Based on comment change this...

```
$('.selected-blog-'+x).load($(this).attr('href'));
```

Comment: Thanks J.Romero!  I had added the text 'id' to those sections as $id is a number and from my understanding you can't start an id with a number.  So the final result would be id="id3" for example.  I've tried your changed code above but I can't get it working.

Comment: In that case, your jquery selector is not matching your displayed ids.

Comment: `var x = this.id;` x would = id3, your selected-blog div is `selected-blog-id3` but the jquery is looking for `$('.selected-blog-,'+x)` which is interpreted into class `.selected-blog` OR `id3` (which isn't a proper selector) because of the comma. **Get rid of the comma and it should work.**

Comment: Thanks J Romero!  I hadn't realised that with the comma.  Very helpful!!